# Extend an hash attribute and prevent overwrite it with coffeescript and marionettejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a view like this:

```
class MyView1 extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
  template: JST['templates/view1']

  regions:
     region1: '.region1'

  ## Here some methods....
```

And now I want extend this class for add some regions and methods

```
class MyView2 extends MyView1
  template: JST['templates/view2']

  regions:
    region2: '.region2'
```

This overwrites template and regions attributes. But I want add the region2 to hash of regions, not overwrite it. So regions would be a hash with region1 and region2.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

```
class MyView1 extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
  template: JST['templates/view1']

  regions:
    region1: '.region1'

class MyView2 extends MyView1
  template: JST['templates/view2']

  MyView2::regions = {}
  for k, v of MyView1::regions
    MyView2::regions[k] = v
  MyView2::regions.region2 = '.region2'
```

But maybe the following would be cleaner and serve your purposes equally well:

```
class MyView1 extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
  constructor: ->
    @regions =
      region1: '.region1'

  template: JST['templates/view1']

class MyView2 extends MyView1
  constructor: ->
    super()
    @regions.region2 = '.region2'

  template: JST['templates/view2']
```

**Edited to use more idiomatic coffeescript `::` instead of `.prototype`, as suggested by comment**

Comment: The second option works correctly and it is more stylish. But the call to super I did it at last, because Marionettejs does some operations over the hash and if called super at top it doesn't work fine.

Comment: You'd usually write `MyView2::regions` instead of `MyView2.prototype.regions` in CoffeeScript.